# Array constrain formula problem in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in Microsoft excel that when uploaded in the google sheet, it turns into zero and was transformed in array_constrain formula. Can somebody help me on this? Below is the excel formula that I used.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(1,CHOOSE({1,2},--EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B),2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(1,CHOOSE({1,2},--EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B),2,0))
```

Can somebody help me transform this into a formula that google sheet will accept? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the formula to work in both? `Excel` and `GoogleSheets`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works on GoogleSheets:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(1,({--EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B}),2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(1,({--EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B}),2,0)))`

The curly brackets with the comma between the parameters is combine the data ranges horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by using the formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B)),0,LOOKUP(1,1/EXACT($A:$A,$F4),$B:$B))
```

Comment: It will give you the last occurrence of `F4` value instead of the first.

Comment: Do you have a better version of the formula Adirmola? I'll be glad to try it out :)